# React/Ionic routing: cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefinded

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, routes

I'm trying to build a tab navigation with Ionic (React). However, I'm getting a weird error - I'm assuming it has something to do with the href attribute of the but I can't make any sense of it.

The exact error is: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined - return props.currentPath.startsWith(href);

Any insight is much appreciated.

TabRoot.js:

```
           <IonRouterOutlet>
                <Route path="/:tab(tab1)" component={NewsPage} exact></Route>
                <Route path="/:tab(tab2)" component={TranslatorPage} exact></Route>
                <Route path="/:tab(tab3)" component={ConverterPage} exact></Route>
            </IonRouterOutlet>

            <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
                <IonTabButton tab="news" href="/tab1">
                    <IonIcon name="flash"></IonIcon>
                </IonTabButton>
                <IonTabButton tab="translator" href="/tab2">
                    <IonIcon name="git-compare" />
                </IonTabButton>
                <IonTabButton tab="converter" href="/tab3">
                    <IonIcon name="cash"></IonIcon>
                </IonTabButton>
            </IonTabBar>
```

App.js:

```
         <Router>
            <div className="App">
             <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/' component={TabRoot}></Route>
            </Switch>
         </div>
         </Router>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling the Ionic tabs starter template fixed the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by reinstalling the starter template? Re-downloading it? Re-running `npm install`?

Comment: Yes, rerunning `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you checkout this ionic react demo https://github.com/mehulmpt/ionic-react-demo 
and this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmrPhSEdVPI

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply. fortunately, reinstalling the ionic tabs starter template fixed the issue (as mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by replacing `<Router>` (imported `{ BrowserRouter as Router } from react-router-dom`) with `<IonReactRouter>` (imported from `@ionic/react-router`).

Answer (score 0):

In my case was a Resources problem, doing:

```
cordova-res
```

Solve my problem

References: [Issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-res/issues/116)